# Qual a origem da expressão "estamos quites"?

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica

Qual origem da  expressão "Estamos quites "

Comment: Procuraste o significado? O que encontraste? Com que dúvidas ficaste ainda?

Comment: Procurei, Não encontrei a origem. Não merece um -

Comment: Atualizei para não sei é a origem

Comment: Se merece um voto-negativo ou não, suponho que isso é para cada votante decidir, não é? :)

Comment: Achei esta pergunta interessante, a expressão é razoavelmente comum em Portugal e nunca me explicaram qual a origem da expressão. Aliás, descubro nesta thread que quitar é verbo, sendo facto que nunca se ouve ou lê conjugado senão como é citado na pergunta.

Comment: Também nao fazia ideia que era um verbo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A frase tem um significado direto: o adjetivo "quite" é o mesmo que "pago", "livre de dívida", portanto "estamos quites" significa "não devemos nada um ao outro".

E o verbo quitar tem como [origem](https://dicionario.priberam.org/quite):

> o francês *quitter*, do latim *quieto*, *-are*, acalmar, aquietar

Answer (score 4):

Quite é o partícipio irregular do verbo quitar, que por sua vez significa "livrar de uma dívida/obriga".

Comment: OK, o significado está claro. E a outra metade da pergunta: a origem?

Comment: Acredito que "Estamos quites" não é nada mais especial do que "Estou bonito", por exemplo. Portanto, a origem de "Estamos quites" basicamente se resume à origem da palavra "quite", o que é facilmente googável.

Comment: Condordo completamente com o que comentas. Mas o significado também é facilmente googlável, e deste-te ao trabalho de o incluir. :)